# Display data from Neo4j database into Java jtable

Tags: java, database, neo4j, jtable

I have created a database in Neo4j and I have a query that displays two terms that occur together in the database. Now I can do this in Neo4j and it displays in a table for me but I am creating an application in java and I want to display it in a JTable. This is what I have so far:

```
    public void dataList(){
                  ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

                  try { 
                       // code 
                      if(result.length>0)
                      {   for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                          {    neoQuery.set("query"+results[i]);
                               neoQuery.add ("query"); //etc
                               //Get Result like this
                                results[results.length-1]=recordVariable.get("recordVariable.get("recordNumbers").asInt();
                           }//end for each record

                               neoQuery.set("query"{+word1+"@"+word2+""})");
                               neoQuery.add("query"); //etc
                               //and result for strings which I want in another column like this
                               resultString = session.run(neoQuery.get()).next().get("result").asString();

                               Data data;
                               while(resultVariable.next() != null){
                                    data = new Data((ResultSet) resultVariable).getInt("c4"), ((ResultSet) resultVariable).getString("w4"));
                                    dataList.add(data);
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                       } catch (Exception e){
                           System.out.println(e);
                      }
                    }
```

I also have another class for how I want to display the data. This is the code.

```
public class Data {
       private int c4;
       private String w4;

       public Data(int c4, String w4)
       {
              this.c4=c4;
              this.w4=w4;
       }
       public int getc4() {
              return c4;
       }
       public String getw4() {
              return w4;
       }
```

So now that I have this code I want to display the data in two columns with unlimited rows. So far I have tried this.

```
public void show_data() {
              ArrayList<Data> list = dataList();
              DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable_Display_Data.getModel();
```

I have done research but just find resources for SQL. Now I can do this for a limited number of rows but I am not so sure how to write the rest for an unlimited number of rows. How can I do this for Neo4j?

Comment: 1) The problem here really has nothing to with either Swing or you IDE. Don't slap those tags on questions they're not an integral part of. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I have done research but just find resources for SQL. How can I do this with Neo4j?"* See [From SQL to Cypher – A hands-on Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sql-to-cypher/).

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at this link.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything about JTables in this link. https://neo4j.com/?s=jtable&x=0&y=0

Comment: Those closing lines I quoted earlier, had me thinking you were having trouble doing queries or updates on Neo4j. Now reading the rest carefully, I'm thoroughly confused. Basically you need to separate this (in your thinking) into two parts. One of those would be accessing & updating the DB. The other would be using data in objects to create a Swing table. Each can be solved separately, and when both are working, easily plugged together. But which part are you asking about? BTW - For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] concentrating on that part of the problem.

Comment: I basically have all the code written and have managed to print out the results. I'm just not sure how to display the data in a Jtable

Comment: and I feel that I have displayed the code in a way that is easy to understand what I am trying to ask.

Comment: *"I'm just not sure how to display the data in a Jtable"* OK. .so show us your best effort at doing that in the form of an MCVE.

Comment: *"I feel that I have displayed the code in a way that is easy to understand what I am trying to ask."* Is it easy for people to get that code to run in their IDE? That's part of the benefit of making an MCVE. Some will actually run the code in their IDE. That can make debugging a problem much easier. Can the reader do a single copy paste of the code above, compile it without any changes, run it to see the problem?

Comment: BTW - you might benefit from going through [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) as it seems that's where you are stuck.